# How to identify if a value exists within a property of an object in a node tree?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to check if the value of `url` exists within the `path` property in any of the objects or nodes of the following tree.

Regarding the tree. The `children` property is optional but if it exists it could be expanded indefinitely

The tree looks similar to the following

```
const items = [
  {
    path: "/admin/dashboard",
    menuIcon: {
      icon: "dashboard",
      title: "toolbar.dashboard",
    },
    // children: [
    //   {
    //     path: "/admin/collection",
    //     menuIcon: {
    //       icon: "summarize",
    //       title: "toolbar.reports",
    //     },
    //   },
    // ],
  },
  {
    path: "/admin/contents",
    menuIcon: {
      icon: "archive",
      title: "toolbar.contents",
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/admin/cigar-house-management",
    menuIcon: {
      icon: "home",
      title: "toolbar.directory-management",
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "/admin/reports",
        menuIcon: {
          icon: "summarize",
          title: "toolbar.reports",
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: "/admin/admin-reports",
            menuIcon: {
              icon: "summarize",
              title: "toolbar.reports",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

In order to achieve the desired result I am using the following function

```
function isValid(url, tree) {
  if (tree && Array.isArray(tree) && tree.length > 0) {
    for (const node of tree) {
      if (node.path === url) {
        return true;
      }

      if (!node.children) {
        continue;
      }

      const found = isValid(url, node.children);

      if (found) {
        return found;
      }

      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Can be checked here

```js
const url = "/admin/admin-reports";
const items = [
  {
    path: "/admin/dashboard",
    menuIcon: {
      icon: "dashboard",
      title: "toolbar.dashboard",
    },
    // children: [
    //   {
    //     path: "/admin/collection",
    //     menuIcon: {
    //       icon: "summarize",
    //       title: "toolbar.reports",
    //     },
    //   },
    // ],
  },
  {
    path: "/admin/contents",
    menuIcon: {
      icon: "archive",
      title: "toolbar.contents",
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/admin/cigar-house-management",
    menuIcon: {
      icon: "home",
      title: "toolbar.directory-management",
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "/admin/reports",
        menuIcon: {
          icon: "summarize",
          title: "toolbar.reports",
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: "/admin/admin-reports",
            menuIcon: {
              icon: "summarize",
              title: "toolbar.reports",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

function isValid(url, tree) {
  if (tree && Array.isArray(tree) && tree.length > 0) {
    for (const node of tree) {
      if (node.path === url) {
        return true;
      }

      if (!node.children) {
        continue;
      }

      const found = isValid(url, node.children);

      if (found) {
        return found;
      }

      return false;
    }
  }
}

const output = isValid(url, items);

console.log(output);
```

But I have noticed that when adding a new node (like the commented node in the tree example), for example as a child of the first node, it does not evaluate the ones after the parent node.

Also, recursion is usually difficult for me so I would appreciate your advice.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function, you're returning either `true` or `false` for every entry that either has a matching path, or has children.  The only way to continue the iteration with your current code is to not match and not have children.

I'd recommend simplifying a bit so it's clearer:

```
function isValid(url, tree) {
  return tree.some(item =>
    item.path === url || (item.children && isValid(url, item.children))
  );
}
```

Comment: you are a sorcerer friend, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

> *"But I have noticed that when adding a new node (like the commented node in the tree example), for example as a child of the first node, it does not evaluate the ones after the parent node."*

Here's you're culprit:

```js
      /* 
      || Without that extra >children< property, the function goes on to find
      || the given search term 
      */ 
      if (!node.children) {
        continue;
      }
      /*
      || But with that extra >children< property on the way the function is 
      || forced to continue onto this snafu. Since the extra >children<
      || property returns as false from isValid(), the control statement 
      || is skipped and goes to the last line which is return false. So the 
      || function terminates because a return statement always terminates the 
      || function thereby never reaching the end of the array. 
      */ 
      const found = isValid(url, node.children);
      if (found) {
        return found;
      }
      /*
      || Do not use a return within a "for" loop. If it is reached then most
      || likely the function terminates too early and the loop never continues 
      || onto the next iteration.
      */
      return false; 
    }
```

**Details are commented in example**

```js
const admin = [{
    title: "Dashboard",
    path: "/admin/dashboard",
    items: [{
      title: "Dashboard Reports",
      path: "/admin/dashboard/reports"
    }]
  },
  {
    title: "Management",
    path: "/admin/management",
    items: [{
      title: "Management Reports",
      path: "/admin/management/reports"
    }]
  },
  {
    title: "Archive",
    path: "/admin/archive",
    items: [{
      title: "Archive Reports",
      path: "/admin/archive/reports",
      items: [{
        title: "Archive Reports Management",
        path: "/admin/archive/reports/management"
      }, {
        title: "Archive Reports Dashboard",
        path: "/admin/archive/reports/dashboard"
      }]
    }]
  }
];

/**
 * Searches for a given string within each object's >path< property value of a
 * given array of objects.
 * @param {String} term - The string segment to search for.
 * @param {Array<object>} struct - The array of objects to search through
 * @returns {Array<array>} - An array of arrays that contain the value of each
 *          >path< property that has >term< within it.
 */
function searchStruct(term, struct) {
  let data = []; // 1
  if (Array.isArray(struct)) {
    for (const node of struct) {
      if (node.path.includes(term)) {
        data.push(node.path); // 2
      }
      if (node.items) {
        data.push(searchStruct(term, node.items)); // 3
      }
    }
  }
  return data; // 4
}

console.log(searchStruct("reports", admin));
/**
 * If you just want a simple true/false returned, replace the line at
 * 1 with: (remove line)
 * 2 with: return true;
 * 3 with: if (searchStruct(term, node.items)) return true;
 * 4 with: return false;
 */
```

To make a function recursive it must:

- state a condition in which it will invoke itself

  ```js
  if (node.items) {
    data.push(searchStruct(term, node.items));
  }
  ```
- this condition must be iterated (within a loop, an array method, etc)
- have a new value passed by a recursively called function

  ```js
  searchStruct(term, node.items)
  // New value passed ⤴️
  ```